# Solving $\frac{\sin x}{4}=\frac{\sin y}{3}=\frac{\sin z}{2}$ where $x$, $y$, $z$ are angles of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

Can any one give me a hint to find value of $x$
where:

> $$\frac{\sin x}{4}=\frac{\sin y}{3}=\frac{\sin z}{2}$$
>   and $x$, $y$, $z$ are angles of a triangle.

I tried to use sine law but got nothing.

Comment: $x=y=z=0$ can be the solution

Comment: x,y and z are angles in a triangle.

Comment: You have a triangle with sides 4, 3, 2 or a SSS triangle. You need to use the Law of Cosines to find the three angles $x,\,y,\,z$.

Comment: you have got 3 variables and 3 equations, could be solved....

Answer (score 2):

$2R=a/sinA=b/sinB=c/sinC$

$a=4 ,b=3 ,c=2$

Heron's formula

$S=1/2*3*2sinx=√9/2*1/2*3/2*5/2$

$sinx=√15/4$

Comment: Heron's formula is the area of the triangle in terms of its sides :Area =$\sqrt {s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ where $s=(a+b+c)/2.$  But there is nothing wrong with your logic.+1

Answer (score 0):

Unless $x, y, z$ represent the angles of a triangle, there'll be infinitely many solutions.

If three sides of a triangle are given, it's better to use cosine law:

\begin{align*}
  \cos x &= \frac{3^{2}+2^{2}-4^{2}}{2(3)(2)} \\
  \cos y &= \frac{4^{2}+2^{2}-3^{2}}{2(4)(2)} \\
  \cos z &= \frac{3^{2}+4^{2}-2^{2}}{2(3)(4)} \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

My solution involves finding the size of angle x. Then getting it's sine.

From the sine law we can tell that the triangle has sides 3, 4 and 2. And that angle x is opposite to the side with length 4.

We can employ cosine law to find the size of angle x.

$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab\cos\theta$

$4^2 = 2^2 + 3 ^2 - 2(3*2)\cos\theta$

This evaluates to

$\cos\theta = -\frac{3}{12} = -0.25$

To get the size of the angle, feed $- 0.25$ into the inverse cos function

$\cos^{-1} (-0.25) = 104.478^\circ $

Finally, get the sine of the angle

$\sin (104.478^\circ) = 0.968 $

Therefore, $\sin  x = 0.968 $